# survey package in R: How to set fpc argument (finite population correction)

Tags: r, random, statistics, sampling, survey

I have sampled some data from a sampling frame using the probability proportional to size (PPS) plan such that I have sampled `6` strata on combination of two variables: `gender` and `pre` with proportions:

```
      pre
gender  High   Low Medium
     F 0.155 0.155  0.195
     M 0.155 0.155  0.185
```

Now I want to specify the design of my sampled data using `svydesign` from R package ["survey"](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/survey.pdf). I was wondering how to define the `fpc` (*finite population correction*) argument?

The documentation says:

> For PPS sampling without replacement it is necessary to specify the probabilities for each stage of sampling using the `fpc` argument, and an overall weight argument should not be given.

```
library(survey)

out <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/d/master/out.csv')

dstrat <- svydesign(id=~1,strata=~gender+pre, data=out, pps = "brewer", fpc = ????)
```

Comment: From the examples, it is a column created in the dataset.  May be you need to do a group by operation by taking the percentage of rows

Comment: Based on [this](https://forum.ipums.org/t/does-anyone-have-sample-code-for-using-svydesign-function-in-r/2444) perhaps you don't need that argument

Comment: @akrun, I emailed the package author, he said: *"You want the fpc = variable to be the sampling probability for that observation (i.e., for the stratum that observation is in)"*. So we need to add a column for `fpc` based on proportions I show in my question. Do you we can add a column for `fpc` to `out` using `tidyverse`?

Comment: You can do that with `out %>% group_by(gender, pre) %>% mutate(fpc = ..)` I don't know the calculation here

Comment: @akrun, there is no calculation. `fpc` for observations on rows that are `High` on `pre` variable and `F` on `gender` is `.155` (look at the table of proportions above:)

Comment: Try `out %>% group_by(gender, pre) %>% summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(fpc = n/sum(n)) %>% right_join(out)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to add proportion column, then we group by 'gender', 'pre', create the percentage by taking the count divided by the `sum` of counts and `left_join`

```
out1 <-  out %>%
           group_by(gender, pre) %>% 
           summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
           mutate(fpc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
           right_join(out)
```

---

Or using `adorn_percentages` from `janitor`

```
library(janitor)
library(tidyr)
out1 <- out %>% 
         tabyl(gender, pre) %>% 
         adorn_percentages(denominator = "all") %>% 
         pivot_longer(cols = -gender, names_to = 'pre', 
             values_to = 'fpc') %>%
        right_join(out)
```

---

If we need a function

```
f1 <- function(dat, grp_cols) {
          dat %>%
             group_by(across(all_of(grp_cols))) %>%
              summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
              mutate(fpc = n/sum(n)) %>% 
              right_join(dat)
  }



f1(out, c("gender", "pre"))
#Joining, by = c("gender", "pre")
# A tibble: 200 x 11
#   gender pre       n   fpc   no. fake.name sector   pretest state email            phone      
#   <chr>  <chr> <int> <dbl> <int> <chr>     <chr>      <int> <chr> <chr>            <chr>      
# 1 F      High     31 0.155     1 Pont      Private     1352 NY    Pont@...com      xxx-xx-6216
# 2 F      High     31 0.155     2 Street    NGO         1438 CA    Street@...com    xxx-xx-6405
# 3 F      High     31 0.155     3 Galvan    Private     1389 NY    Galvan@...com    xxx-xx-9195
# 4 F      High     31 0.155     4 Gorman    NGO         1375 CA    Gorman@...com    xxx-xx-1845
# 5 F      High     31 0.155     5 Jacinto   Private     1386 CA    Jacinto@...com   xxx-xx-6237
# 6 F      High     31 0.155     6 Shah      Public      1384 CA    Shah@...com      xxx-xx-5723
# 7 F      High     31 0.155     7 Randon    Private     1360 TX    Randon@...com    xxx-xx-7542
# 8 F      High     31 0.155     8 Koucherik NGO         1439 NY    Koucherik@...com xxx-xx-9137
# 9 F      High     31 0.155     9 Waters    Industry    1414 TX    Waters@...com    xxx-xx-7560
#10 F      High     31 0.155    10 David     Industry    1396 CA    David@...com     xxx-xx-6498
# … with 190 more rows
```

Comment: Arun, I think I need an answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64229622/adding-elements-of-tables-or-arrays-of-tables-to-a-dataframe-in-r). Thank you.

Comment: I think I got it now:0)